# Are the laws of thought still accepted as the basis of logic?

Tags: logic, identity

The "laws of thought" refers to the three traditional principles said to underlie logical reasoning: identity, non-contradiction, and excluded middle. Are these principles still generally accepted? Is there serious and recent criticism of their value?

Comment: For opposition to the *Law of Non-Contradiction*, see [Dialetheism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/).

Comment: For opposition to the *Law of Excluded Middle*, see [Intuitionsim](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/) and [Intuitionistic Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/).

Comment: The following article may be interesting http://lumiere.ens.fr/~dbonnay/files/Papers/bonnaycozic_whichlogicfortheradicalantirealist.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your first question, "Are these principles still generally accepted?", the empirical evidence suggests that **opinion is divided**.

The same evidence suggests that the answer to your second question, "Is there serious and recent criticism of their value?" is **yes**.

In a relatively recent survey of philosophers, only about half said they accept or lean toward classical logic (see: https://philpapers.org/surveys/results.pl). The rest either said they accept or lean toward non-classical logic, which include logics that violate those "laws of thought" you mentioned, or responded "Other".

Non-classical logics generally reject (or give new meaning to) at least one of these traditional "laws of thought." Examples:

- Many-valued logic, which goes back to Aristotle, and which doesn't accept the traditional  law of excluded middle
- Intuitionist logic, which also doesn't include the law of the excluded middle (and also gets rid of double negation elimination)
- Non-reflexive / "Schrödinger" logic, which leaves out or loosens the law of identity (see Schrödinger, E., 1952, Science and Humanism).
- Linear logic, where the law of excluded middle gets very weird interpretations (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-linear/)

One last note: Dialetheism is a view that gets some attention. It's not a formal system of logic like the ones mentioned above. Dialetheism, in its crazier form, is the thesis that there can be a true statement whose negation is also true. In a saner (but still crazy) form, it is the thesis that sometimes the best theory is contradictory. Outside of Western philosophy, I would guess that Dialetheism is actually quite popular (Zen Buddhists, for example, often seem to accept it), but I don't have empirical evidence to support that conclusion.